# How to take a specific word from long text to make a variable?

Tags: php, regex, variables, preg-replace

I want to take a specific word from long text to make a variable. I'm using these codes;

```html
function hashtag($str){
    $regex = "/(#)+[a-zA-Z0-9]+/";
 $str = preg_replace($regex, '<a href="e.php?tag=\\0")">\\0</a>', $str);
    return($str);
}
```

It makes a hashtag;

Text: Robert De Niro won the #oscar.

After code: Robert De Niro won the [#oscar](http://www.website.com/e.php?tag=#oscar).

(___e.php?tag=#oscar)

But I want to make a variable with "oscar" and make the link like this;

Robert De Niro won the [#oscar](http://www.website.com/e.php?tag=oscar).

(___e.php?tag=oscar)

I mean If I could make a variable ($variable), I can use it wherever I want.

If you can help me I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple:

```
<?php
function hashtag($str){
    $regex = "/#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/";
    $str = preg_replace($regex, '<a href="e.php?tag=\\1">\\0</a>', $str);
    return($str);
}
```

The only thing to do is to **capture the part after the hash tag** and use this as your `tag` variable afterwards.

See a <kbd>[demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/Gj8Tqi)</kbd>.